# jbpm 5.4 with mysql

Tags: jboss, jbpm, business-process-management

I'm using jBPM 5.4 with the inbuild database H2.

It works fine.

I need to migrate from H2 to MySql/MS-SQL.

Hence i followed this useful link, https://community.jboss.org/wiki/SetUpJBPM54FinalInstallerToUseMSSQLServer2008UsingJTDS

But as specified i dont have `ant install.demo.db`

can anyone please help me in porting to MySQL/MS-SQL ?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is been changed to `ant install.db.files`  but not notified in user guide.